# Irreducible Galois representation and lattices

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

Let $\scr{G}$ be the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}_p$ vector space where $\scr{G}$ acts. Consider the representation 
$$\rho:\scr{G} \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q}_p).$$

I have tried to show the following statement:

$\textit{If $\rho$ is irreducible then there exist only a finite number of stable lattices in $V$ (up to homothety)}$.

However, each of my attempts have miserably failed.

Could ask you an hint?

My first idea was: let $\Lambda_1,\dots,\Lambda_r$ be the stable lattices under the action of $\scr{G}$. Assume there exist a subrepresentation $W$ of $V$. By the theory I know that exist $\Lambda_W$ stable under the action of $\scr{G}$. However, I am not able to show that if I complete $\Lambda_W$ to a rank $n$ lattice then I find a lattice different of the $\Lambda_i$'s stable. (and probably this way is totally wrong)

Comment: And the answer is in the homothety part : if you can split the representation (and hence any lattice) into $(\rho',W) \oplus (\rho'',W^{\perp})$ then you can apply a different homothety to each part of the lattice, and that will yield an infinite number of lattices ?

Comment: Since if $\Lambda_{W}$ then $\lambda \Lambda_W$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{Q_p}$ will be a stable lattice. The same for a stable lattice of the other part. changing $\lambda, \lambda^{'}$ I will obtained infinite non homothetic stable lattice. (probably I am not correct)

Comment: the projection of a lattice is a lattice. But is it always true that $\Lambda = \Lambda_W \oplus \Lambda_{W^\perp}$ for any subspace $W$  and any lattice ?

Comment: Isn't user1952009's argument proving the **converse** of the statement that the poster asked for?

Comment: @DavidLoeffler you are perfectly right. Do you know if $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (and $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}/\mathbb{Q}_p)$) is special here, or if any non-finite field works ?

Comment: Any compact group will do in place of $\mathscr{G}$. It's just a question about subgroups of $GL_n(\mathbf{Q}_p)$.